# Compilation error with ButterKnife: error duplicate class

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle, butterknife

I get this error when I build my project:

error: duplicate class: class_name$$ViewInjector

[image]

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.stel.order"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {  
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'   
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
  ...
}
```

If I clean the project, it builds without errors, but when I run the project, I get this error.

Comment: Here is the elaborated solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219175/android-studio-butterknife-6-1-0-duplicate-class-view-injector

Answer (score 4):

It happened with me too when I migrated from Eclipse. All you need is to delete files `path.OuterClass$$ViewInjector` in your project manually.

Comment: Here is the elaborated solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219175/android-studio-butterknife-6-1-0-duplicate-class-view-injector

Answer (score 0):

1: Remove the eclipse project .apt_generated file folders and .factorypath
2: Remove .classpath file  node
3: re-imported into the android studio

1：删除eclipse项目中的.apt_generated文件夹和.factorypath文件
2：删除.classpath文件中的节点
3：重新导入到android studio中

Comment: Hi Jack, posting your answer in English and Chinese may be helpful to those whose grasp of English isn't that good, but it could be argued that every post should be written in all languages that a user knows to be helpful. Please see ["*Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?*"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676) for a discussion on the subject. Thank you.