# Android Studio: ButterKnife 6.1.0 Duplicate Class: $$View Injector

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

I migrated my project to AS from Eclipse as I was getting 65K methods issue. After fixing every dependency issue that I was facing initially with AS, I got stuck with this issue which doesn't seem to go away no matter what I try from the other similar posts from around the blogs and SO itself.

[image: default settings]

I checked *Enable Annotation Processing* in  Annotation Processors and also gave a processor path.  (even tried with Obtain processor from project classpath) but whenever I run the project it gives the following  error:

```
Error:(8, 8) error: duplicate class: list.EventsListAdapter$ViewHolder$$ViewInjector 
Error:Execution failed for task ':ProjectDemo:compileDebugJava'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

In my gradle file, I added the following as per the suggestions by others:

```
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def file = output.outputFile
            output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
        }
    }
```

But the result was the same.

What am I doing wrong? Also, let me know if you want more details regarding this. I'm kinda new to AS and might have missed something obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also faced this issue. This issue occurred when user imported project from eclipse's workspace. Actually it copies the `$$ViewInjector.java` files in your `src` folder. So you need to delete them from your `src` packages manually.

Comment: Oh yes! That's so silly thing done by Android Studio. Yes, it solved it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, don't have the reputation to add the comment to @Rakesh's answer (he is right).

It also happens when "refactor - move package" with wrong options.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the heads up. :) Now you have rep to comment as well. xD